# Get value from Jtable and set it to JcomboxBox in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jtable, jcombobox

I want to ask if there is a way to get the value from a Jtable and set it to a JcomboBox.

I insert data into database using jcomboboxes, and I want to get the value of what I inserted to database.

I'm using netbeans & mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it.

**One Way**

You need to get data from JTable using `getValueAt(row,column)` and them you can add that value to JComboBox using `addItem(value)` like:

```
comboBox.addItem(table.getValueAt(row,column).toString());
```

**Second Way**

As you are using `mysql resultset` to get fill the jtable, you can use that resultset to set the combobox value too like:

You can use a loadcombo() to load your combobox with database values.

```
void loadcombo() {
    try
    {
    // Your database connections 

rs= st.executeQuery("select Column from Table");
    while(rs.next()){                            
        jComboBox.addItem(rs.getString(1));
    }
    con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error"+e);
    }    
}
```

**I suggest you to use second way**

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
comboBox.setSelectedItem(table.getValueAt(row,column).toString());
```

Where `comboBox` is the name of the `ComboBox` and `table` is the name of the table in question.

`.setSelectedItem` sets the item in the `JTable` to display on the combo box. You can read the [`JComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) docs for more information about this.

Comment: This might be an answer but add more information to support your answer.

Comment: @AniMenon Thanks but there's no need for a minus rep there.

Comment: @T Lin Good you have added some info, do try to improve your answer by adding supporting information. (The negative rep was to get your attention. I have removed it now)

Comment: @AniMenon Thank you for both the lesson and removing the negative rep.